# YouTube API search/list empty snippet description

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm playing with https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list and noticed something weird with the following parameters in the test section:

- part: snippet
- channelId: UCtBxYxmrsZrP1NPMttH-VOg
- maxResults: 50
- type: video

Then, click "Execute without OAuth " and the results appear.

Search for the string "Antonio", and you will notice the snippet is not truncated (as it happens on other videos), but empty.

The video has a description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6XOBGW6coI

Am I doing something wrong? Is this intended?

Comment: You are using thhe API for JavaScript or for Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a defect with the v3 API (similar bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5731)).  Not all videos returned from the `search/list` endpoint for a channel will return a description at all.

If the description for a video is empty, from your first query, you would have to perform an additional API request to the [`videos/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with `part=snippet` and `id={videoId from the previous query}` to return the correct description.

Comment: Thank you JAL! I will try the additional request approach.